# PHP--> Created a class, but assigning values to the properties fail

Tags: php, class, properties, instantiation

I'm creating a class and attempting to use it.  However, the values I set are not being retained.  Please advise!

Here's my class definition:

```
<?php
class MemberData
{
var $mdId;
var $mdFname;
var $mdLname;
var $mdEmail;
var $mdTwitter;
var $mdFacebook;
var $mdMyspace;
var $mdPhoneNumber;
var $mdNotes;

function MemberData($mdId, $mdFname, $mdLname, $mdEmail, $mdTwitter, $mdFacebook, $mdMyspace, $mdPhoneNumber, $mdNotes)
{
        $this->mdId = $mdId;
        $this->mdFname = $mdFname;
        $this->mdLname = $mdLname;
        $this->mdEmail = $mdEmail;
        $this->mdTwitter = $mdTwitter;
        $this->mdFacebook = $mdFacebook;
        $this->mdMyspace = $mdMyspace;
        $this->mdPhoneNumber = $mdPhoneNumber;
        $this->mdNotes = $mdNotes;

}//end function

}//end MemberData class
?>
```

Here's where I instantiate the class and attempt to set and  print one of the property values:

```
<?php

include("./classes/MemberData.php");

$listMember = new MemberData();

echo "herexy";

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
                switch($c){

                        case 0: $listMember->mdFname=$data[$c];break;
                        //case 0: $listMember->mdFname["blue"];break;
                        case 0: break;
                        //case 1: $listMember->mdLname($data[$c]);break;
                        case 2: echo "c==$c<br>";break;
                        case 3: echo "c==$c<br>";break;
                        case 4: echo "c==$c<br>";break;
                        case 5: echo "c==$c<br>";break;

                }//end switch
        }
        print "listmember->mdFname == $listmember->mdFname";
    }//end while
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: I would use getters and setters in the class to access the class variables.

Comment: Why don't you just use arrays and a map from column number to key? Would be much easier. You can then later on convert the arrays into objects if you like.

Comment: Why do you have two `case 0:` statements?

Comment: And add a `default` case that throws an exception so you know when you missed something.

Comment: Also, each time you perform a successful read from the csv file you modifying the `mdFName` member.

Comment: You're using an object just as a data storage.  You really don't need an object in this case.  to the other users, using his framework, when/why would you use objects?

Comment: @tmjam, Thank you.  Do you suggest add a getter and a setter function along with what I already have?

Comment: @phpmeh: Well, it's an entity definition.  The variables map to table fields and when I make it past this step I'll add the CRUD methods.

Comment: @KristerAndersson,  OK, I printed @ each case statement, and I see that data is being stored.  But after the for loop goes through each array element, shouldn't my class variables be populated with the data from each of the case statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `case 0` statements.  I don't use `switch` statements very often but I'm pretty sure that's not the way `switch` statements are supposed to be used.

I would rewrite your switch to look something like this:

```
switch ($c) {
    case 0:
        $listMember->mdFname=$data[$c];
        break;
    default:
        echo "c==$c<br>";
}
```

Otherwise, your values aren't being assigned because you aren't passing anything to the parameters of the constructor.  You would need to assign values when you create the object:

`$listMember = new MemberData($arg1, $arg2, ...);`.

Right now the only property that should be set is `mdFname` and only when `$c` is equal to `0`.  However, with 2 `case 0:` statements I'm not sure what the interpreter do here and may very well not assign the property any value.

Should [read about classes and objects with PHP 5](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why it doesn't work, but you are doing some things really strangely.

I'd suggest using an array rather than managing all the properties:

```
class MemberData {

    public $properties; //I'd recommend private or protected.

    function MemberData(array $data) {
        $this->properties['mdId'] = isset($data['mdId']) ? $data['mdId'] : null;
        $this->properties['mdFname'] = isset($data['mdFname']) ? $data['mdFname'] : null;
        $this->properties['mdLname'] = isset($data['mdLname']) ? $data['mdLname'] : null;
        $this->properties['mdEmail'] = isset($data['mdEmail']) ? $data['mdEmail'] : null;
        $this->properties['mdTwitter'] = isset($data['mdTwitter']) ? $data['mdTwitter'] : null;
        $this->properties['mdFacebook'] = isset($data['mdFacebook']) ? $data['mdFacebook'] : null;
        $this->properties['mdMyspace'] = isset($data['mdMyspace']) ? $data['mmdMyspacedId'] : null;
        $this->properties['mdPhoneNumber'] = isset($data['mdPhoneNumber']) ? $data['mdPhoneNumber'] : null;
        $this->properties['mdNotes'] = isset($data['mdNotes']) ? $data['mdNotes'] : null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, sure as you asked for   ---

```
public function get_mdNotes(){return $this->mdNotes;} set_mdNotes($notes){$this->mdNotes = $notes;}
```